# Question about the cardinality

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

Let Let I denote the collection of all nonempty open intervals in R with rational endpoints,
$$I = \{(a, b) : a, b \in\mathbb Q, a < b\}$$
What is the cardinality of I?

Let O denote the collection of all countable unions of open intervals in I.
What is the cardinality of O?

Answer (score 4):

$\aleph_0$.

You can identify each interval in $I$
(bijectively)
by its pair of endpoints $\{(q_1,q_2)\in\mathbb{Q}^2\mid
q_1<q_2\}$.
Then use $|I|=|\mathbb{Q}^2| = |\mathbb{Q}|=|\mathbb{N}| = \aleph_0$.

Comment: Consider instead constructing a bijection between $I$ and ($\mathbb{Q}^2 - \{ (q, q) : q \in \mathbb{Q} \}$). That is, take away the diagonal. You can show that ($\mathbb{Q}^2 - \{ (q, q) : q \in \mathbb{Q} \}$) has countably infinite cardinality.

Comment: Welcome to the community, Jiu! Typically people don't ask additional questions in the comments. You might see if you can alter the argument I gave to prove this, but if you're stuck, you should just post it as a separate question.